# Git revert in master reverting commits when merged into feature branch

Tags: git

I have been developing a major, long-term feature on a separate branch, `big-feature`. During its development, I have also been making smaller unrelated updates on `master` (well, technically I have been making the smaller updates on their own branches from `master` and then merging them into `master`.)

Each time I complete some changes to `master`, I have been in the habit of also merging `master` into `big-feature` so that the feature branch doesn't stray too far from `master` and the merge will be hopefully easier when the big feature is complete.

However, after some recent work, I accidentally merged `big-feature` into `master`. I attempted to rectify this with `revert`, and indeed the previous code state seems to have been restored. However, I still see the full history of commits from `big-feature` listed in the commit history of `master`, plus a `merge` and `revert` at the top.

The problem is, when I now make a small change on `master` and attempt to merge `master` into `big-feature`, all of `big-feature`'s code reverts to that of `master`. I can only guess that the `revert` from `master` is being merged into `big-feature` and removing all the commits in `big-feature`.

Hopefully this is semi-coherent.

Questions:

1. Is my diagnosis correct?
2. Is my strategy of periodically merging `master` into `big-feature` a bad idea?
3. The main question: how do I fix this?

P.S. I also tried a `hard reset` of `master` to the commit before the erroneous merge, but this didn't remove all of the commits from `big-feature`, which surprised me?

Comment: could you explain in more details "this didn't remove all of the commits from big-feature" ? Perhaps with a view of the history you see ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I accidentally merged big-feature into master. I attempted to rectify this with revert

That's not how to undo a merge.

A revert is a whole *new* commit, which is artificially created in such a way as to add to the future history the negation of some commit that came before it.

The way to undo the merge is to be on the branch you were on when you did the merge and simply `reset --hard` back one commit, namely to the commit just before the merge commit. It has no name so you have to use `HEAD~1` notation or use the SHA of that commit. The merge commit is thrown away, and presto, we are right back where we were before the merge.

(You say you tried that, but you don't give the actual command that you gave, so there is no reason to think you gave the command correctly.)

In this example, I have created commits A, B, and C on `master` and commit Z on `feature`, and I have merged `feature` into `master` — you can tell that because (1) I am *on* `master`, and (2) the merge commit is part of `master`, not part of `feature`:

```
*   a65559d (HEAD -> master) merge commit
|\  
| * c6c9d90 (feature) Z
* | caa732e C
* | 11bbc44 B
|/  
* 92e934a A
```

Note the SHA numbers. Let's say we regret this move. So our goal is to delete `a65559d` in such a way as to put `master` back at `caa732e`, where it was before we merged `feature`. We are currently *on* `master`, so all we have to do is say:

```
git reset --hard caa732e
```

Result:

```
* c6c9d90 (feature) Z
| * caa732e (HEAD -> master) C
| * 11bbc44 B
|/  
* 92e934a A
```

Exactly what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks, I tried `git reset --hard <SHA>` using the SHA of the commit just before the erroneous merge. This was after the revert, so I was going back a couple of commits with this reset.

Comment: Well, that was right and undid the merge (and the revert, rightly). I don't know why it seemed that it didn't. I've just proved with my actual example that this works as desired.

Comment: I must have made a mistake. I'll try again.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** This answer is only applicable if you are able to overwrite history. You should only do it if you haven't pushed you changes to remote or if you know for a FACT that this won't affect other developers (e.g. there are none or you can communicate to everyone working on the project what you are about to do)

---

> how do I fix this?

I'm assuming that what happened when you merged `big-feature` to master was a [**fast-forward merge**](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/git-merge#:%7E:text=Fast%20Forward%20Merge,to%20the%20target%20branch%20tip.).

In that case, using `git reset` to reset to some specific commit *may not work* as our commits from `master` and `big-feature` may have become mixed. Instead we can use [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to find the state `master` was in before we've made the merge and then reset `master` to that state.

```
git reflog master # Show the history of updates to the tip of master.
                  # Find the line that says "master{n}: merge big-feature: Fast-forward"
                  # and note the reference number n

git switch master # checkout master if necessary
git reset --keep master@{n+1} # Now reset master to the reference just before merge
```

> Is my strategy of periodically merging master into big-feature a bad idea?

If, again, you can overwrite history I would recommend periodically [rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase) your `feature` branch on `master` instead. This gives you an advantage of having a clean history on your `feature` branch, which makes interacting with the branch easier, including in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem here is that when you now merge `master` into `big-feature`, Git is pulling along that merge revert commit, which is then functionally undoing a bunch of your work which happened in `big-feature`.  While there might be a more graceful way to handle this, an easy solution would be to just cherry pick the commits from `master` which you want to also include in `big-feature`:

```
# from big-feature
git cherry-pick ABCD
```

The above assumes that `ABCD` is the SHA-1 hash of the commit in `master` which has the minor fix which you want to bring into `big-feature`.

Using this approach is more work, because you need to figure out exactly which commit(s) need to come in, but it avoids the merge brute force approach which is no longer working for you.